# How to generate JPA Hibernate Metamodel classes in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea

I'm trying to generate Metamodel classes with Hibernate in IntelliJ idea.
I already saw oldest tutorials, but they didn't help me.
There are any other way to generate that files? The topics that I found about Metamodel support in IntelliJ are too old.
Maybe I'm doing something wrong. I'll explain what I'm doing.

I've already tried:

- Enable the processing in IntelliJ settings: Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Annotation Processors > [check] Enable annotation processing.
- Put the maven-processor  in pom.xml. (`jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor`)
- Rebuilt the project.

Plugin that I included in pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>process</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/metamodel</outputDirectory>
                            <compilerArguments>
                                -Aeclipselink.persistencexml=${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml
                            </compilerArguments>
                            <processors>
                                <processor>org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor
                                </processor>
                            </processors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: With that configurations and rebuilding the project, my ```src/main/java``` folder turns empty! And a "generated" folder appears in my ```target``` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Put following dependency in pom.xml of project.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-jpamodelgen -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>

    </dependency>
```

Then use `..path_to_root_directory_of_module_of_entities/target/classes/` directory on the build path of module/project.
It will make available all auto generated static model classes to the runtime of project.